# Bootstap DataTable showing No matching records found Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am developing a project in Django where users can share files.  I retrieve data(files) from the database and show it in a table on the template and use bootstrap DataTable to implement search functionality in my table But when I search any record from DataTable it shows me `No matching records found`.

**Bootstrap Datatable CSS CDN**

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
```

**Bootstrap Datatable Javascript CDN**

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

**Bootstrap script to show data table functionality in a HTML table**

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#datatable').DataTable();

    } );

    </script>
```

Template Code:

```html
{% extends 'instructor/admin_base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block body %}
    <div id="page-container" >
    <main id="main-container">
    <div class="content"> 
    <h3 class="text-center notesText">All Notes</h3><br> 
    `<div class="tablecss container  mt-5" ><div >
    <!--id="datatable" is used for implementing boostrap dataTable features in table-->
    <table id="datatable" class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full-pagination" style=" color:gray;">
                  

    <thead style="background-color : #607d8b; color:white;" >
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.No</th>
                        <th>Uploading Date</th>
                        <th>Branch</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Download Notes</th>
                        <th>File Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </th

    {% for i in notes %}
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.uploadingdate}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.branch}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.subject}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{i.notesfile.url}}" class="btn btn-success" download>Download</a></td>
                    <td>{{i.filetype}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                
                    <td><a href="{% url 'dashboard:delete_notes' i.id %}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are your sure to Delete ?')">Delete</a></td>
                    
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>`</div>`
    </main>
    </div>
```

Views.py (In which I'd like to implement search functinality)

```py
def all_notes(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login_admin')
    notes = Upload_Notes.objects.all()
    context = {'notes':notes}
    return render(request, 'instructor/all_notes.html',context)
```

dashboard/urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name="dashboard"
urlpatterns=[
    path('pending_notes', views.pending_notes, name='pending_notes'),
    path('assign_status/<int:pk>', views.assign_status, name='assign_status'),
    path('accepted_notes', views.accepted_notes, name='accepted_notes'),
    path('rejected_notes', views.rejected_notes, name='rejected_notes'),
    path('all_notes', views.all_notes, name='all_notes'),
    path('admin_home',views.admin_home,name="admin_home"),
    path("showallusers", views.show_all_users, name="showallusers"),

]
```

Models.py

```py
class Upload_Notes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uploadingdate = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    notesfile = models.FileField(null=True,validators=(validate_file_extension,))
    filetype = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} notes'
```

delete_notes view

```
def delete_notes(request,pk=None):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('login')
notes = Upload_Notes.objects.get(id=pk)
notes.delete()
messages.success(request,f"  Notes  delated  successfully!")
return  redirect('/all_notes')
```

Like `all_notes` I have 3 other method for displaying `pending_notes` ,`accepted_notes` and `rejected_notes`.

Template image with error message `no matching record found`
[image]

Extra:
Datatable is working perfectly in another table where I am showing all user info.I am not able to find the problem why data table is not working in the notes table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check [`Ajax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)<sup>[mdn-reference]</sup>, in short ajax gives us the functionality to do CRUD operations in the webpage without reloading the page.

In your code you can implement delete functionality of without reloading page in the following way:

Template file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-container" >
    <main id="main-container">
    <div class="content"> 
    <h3 class="text-center notesText">All Notes</h3><br> 
    <div class="tablecss container  mt-5" ><div>
          <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <p class="main-message"></p>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
    <!--id="datatable" is used for implementing boostrap dataTable features in table-->
    <table id="datatable" class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter js-dataTable-full-pagination" style=" color:gray;">
             
   

    <thead style="background-color : #607d8b; color:white;" >
        {% csrf_token %}
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.No</th>
                        <th>Uploading Date</th>
                        <th>Branch</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Download Notes</th>
                        <th>File Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </th
    
    {% for i in notes %}
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.uploadingdate}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.branch}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.subject}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{i.notesfile.url}}" class="btn btn-success" download>Download</a></td>
                    <td>{{i.filetype}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                
                    <td><button notesid="{{i.id}}" class="btn btn-danger remove-notes">Delete</button></td>
                    
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div></div>
    </main>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
    <script>
                    let messageBox =document.getElementsByClassName("alert-success")[0].children[0];
            if (messageBox.innerHTML == "") {
            console.log(messageBox.parentNode);
            messageBox.parentNode.style.display = "none";
            }

            // main jquery ajax function
            $(".remove-notes").click(function () {
            confirmation = confirm("Are you sure to delete");
            if (confirmation) {
                let elm = this;
                let id = elm.getAttribute("notesid").toString();
                console.log(id);

                $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRFToken": $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
                },
                });
                console.log(id);
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'dashboard:delete_notes' %}",

                data: {
                    notesid: id,
                },
                success: function (resp) {
                    // console.log(status);
                    // resp means response
                    console.log("data is coming");
                    console.log(resp.msg);
                    elm.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                    if (resp.msg != "") {
                    let messageBox = document.getElementsByClassName("alert-success")[0].children[0];
                    messageBox.parentNode.style.display = "block";
                    messageBox.innerHTML = resp.msg;
                    }
                },
                error: function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                },
                });
            }
            });

    </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

views.py

```py
def all_notes(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login_admin')
    notes = Upload_Notes.objects.all()
    context = {'notes': notes}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/all_notes.html', context)


def delete_notes(request, pk=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
        print(request.POST.get('notesid'))
        notes = Upload_Notes.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('notesid')))
        notes.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'msg': 'Notes deleted successfully !'})
```

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "dashboard"
urlpatterns = [
    path('all_notes/', views.all_notes, name='all_notes'),
    path('delete-records/', views.delete_notes, name='delete_notes')
]
```